# HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() times out after some time

Tags: httpwebrequest, compact-framework

I have application that sends requests to same REST server constantly and after some time HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() starts timing out i've noticed that whenever i increase System.Net.ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit it takes it longer to start timing out again, which should mean that those requests are staying active, but as far as i know i'm closing all of them.

Here is method i'm using for my requests.

Current DefaultConnectionLimit is set to 10.

Also there is 1 request that is going on throughout most of applications lifetime.

I'm using .NET Compact framework and REST server is written using WCF (.NET 4.5)

```
public static string HttpRequest(string request, string method, string contentType, int timeout)
     {
                string result = "";
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PodesavanjaManager.TrenutnaPodesavanja.PutanjaServisa + "/" + request);
                req.Method = method;
                req.ContentType = contentType;
                req.Timeout = timeout;
                req.KeepAlive = false;
                if(method == "POST")
                    req.ContentLength = 0;
                using(Stream stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        reader.Close();
                    }
                    stream.Close();
                    stream.Flush();
                }
                return result;
      }
```

EDIT new version of method:

```
public static string HttpRequest(string request, string method, string contentType, int timeout)
{

    string result = "";
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(PodesavanjaManager.TrenutnaPodesavanja.PutanjaServisa + "/" + request);
    req.Method = method;
    req.ContentType = contentType;
    req.Timeout = timeout;
    req.KeepAlive = false;


    if(method == "POST")
        req.ContentLength = 0;
    using (HttpWebResponse resp =(HttpWebResponse) req.GetResponse())
    {
        using (Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                result = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    GC.Collect(); 
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why do you use stream.Close and Flush inside using(stream).. The using automatically will close and dispose the stream. I would not use using and get full control to be able to use Close and Flush. Add an explicit req.Dispose() and req=null at the end. In another SO question GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); is used to force the object dispose.

Comment: I agree that you don't need both `Close` and `using`, but I would personally go for the `using` variant - any exception would keep the connection in use without proper error handling. And `Flush` after `Close` seems a bit weird.

Comment: Yep that was my bad, but afaik at the end of using block both should happen anyway soo i removed them all together, anyways i updated post with new version of my method.

Answer (score 0):

I agree it does *behave* like the connection is still in use by a resource that has not been closed. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse(v=vs.110).aspx) for `HttpWebResponse` mentions:

> You must call either the Stream.Close or the HttpWebResponse.Close method to close the response and release the connection for reuse. It is not necessary to call both Stream.Close and HttpWebResponse.Close, but doing so does not cause an error.

I was hoping for a more straightforward description like "you must either close the stream returned by `GetResponseStream` or call the `HttpWebResponse.Close` method - but if my interpretation of the documentation is correct, your code is fine.

We use HttpWebRequest in our CE applications as well, and always put the response in a `using` block as well - you could try this:

```
using(HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
using(Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
{
    // ...
}
```

Also have you checked your code for other `HttpWebRequest` usages, just to be sure?

Comment: i tried doing this few hours ago, still getting timeouts, i noticed that timeouts happen when i send multiple requests one after another updated post with current version of my method.